# How can I disable filter "category" from Sidebar

Tags: category, layout, filter

I choose my Category XY and get the Product-Grid, on the left side there is the Sub-navigation and below the "Filter Navigation".

The attribute filters starts with "categories", "manufacturer", "size", ..

How can I disable/remove the filter "categories" from sidebar?

I tried per CSS with

```
#narrow-by-list dt:first-child {display:none;}
```

but I cannot remove the categories itself. In which XML I have to remove some blocks? I have no idea ..  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your theme `catalog.xml` file replace the following line

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" />
```

with

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
    <action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
</block>
```

If you're curious why it works, see `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View::_prepareLayout()`

Comment: It works, thank you! Yeah, I'm curious .. but still after looking at Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer ... ;)   It's time for a Magento-Dev.Book ...

Comment: Why should they not do this in the theme's *local.xml*?

Comment: I don't know ;)  Here's the local.xml from my theme: http://jsfiddle.net/mobilat/977BN/   Should I try it with the local.xml - but it works anyway.

Comment: Cool, but it is not working with the `Bubblesearch catalog search page`...

Comment: Ahh this works: `<reference name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
            <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
        </reference>`

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this is an older question, but I found this via Google. 
For any fellow (future) Googlers;

The (currently) recommended way to make layout changes is using a theme's `local.xml`. So when using `local.xml`, add the following:

```
    <catalog_category_layered>
         <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
            <action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

And if you want, you can add the regular (non-filterable) category menu above the filters like by adding the following to your `local.xml`:

```
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.categories" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
            <action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Maurice's answer but modified it slightly:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.categories" template="catalog/navigation/sidebar.phtml"/>
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Category option from Layered Navigation options list in magento

This is what I did to remove the “Category” section from my layered navigation so I wouldnt have any repeat information with the attributes I wanted in the layered navigation.
go to app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/layer and open up view.phtml for edit.

```
<dl id="narrow-by-list"><?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
<?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
 <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
<?php if($_filter->getName() != "Category"){ ?><dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
<dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd><?php } endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?></dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very old question but it can help to any one who have same stuff like me.

To Remove category list from sidebar you can modify xml files as below.

## Remove from layered navigation:

Add below code in `local.xml` file if theme have such file:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
     <reference name="catalog.leftnav">           
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>category_filter</child>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Add below code in `catalog.xml` file if `local.xml` not exists:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <child>category_filter</child>
    </action>       
</block>
```

## Remove from category default page:

Add below code in `local.xml` file if theme have such file:

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav" >       
    <action method="unsetChild">
         <child>category_filter</child>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Add below code in `catalog.xml` file if `local.xml` not exists:

```
 <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
   <action method="unsetChild">
         <child>category_filter</child>
    </action>
 </block>
```

## Remove from catalog search page:

Add below code in `local.xml` file if theme have such file:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
   <reference name="catalog.leftnav">           
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>category_filter</child>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Add below code in `catalogsearch.xml` file if `local.xml` not exists:

```
<block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
      <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>category_filter</child>
        </action>
</block>
```

**Note:** Please clear your cache if you have enabled it in your admin.

Answer (score -3):

Go to Catalog > Attribute > Manage Attribute and go to the price attribute and color attribute click on both and in frontend properties their is "Use In Layered Navigation" make it as NO. and save

Comment: This will remove the price and color attributes from the filter - the question was how to disable the category. The category isn't even an attribute, so this answer doesn't apply to the question in any way as far as I can see...