# Hide or remove "category" filter from the layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout, layered-navigation

I'm struggling to remove the Category filter from the layered, because I already have a category dropdown menu in my new website, so it will be only a waste of space (and confuse my customers)

I know that this issue was already asked many times and already solved, but I tried every solution without success. I believe that this is related to the custom template I use for the website.

After looking at my local.xml file (found in my template folder)  I believe that I should work around these lines:

```
<reference name="product_list">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="category-right" as="category-right" translate="label">
            <label>Right Column</label>
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/category_nav.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="catalog.category" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
            <block type="filterproducts/bestsellers_home_list" name="bestseller" template="catalog/navigation/best_sellers.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
                <block type="cms/block" name="cms_images_block">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>category_right_block</block_id></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

The first -**block type**- should be the category menu (and I'm fine with that). The second -**block type**- builds the "filter by" menu, just below the category menu, and I'm pretty sure that the problem is here.

I believe that I should unset something inside the "catalog.leftnav"  but even if I try to add this code :

```
<catalog_category_layered>
     <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you just need to avoid category section from layered navigation and dont want to avoid other filters?

Comment: exactly! 
but I'm going crazy to find out how....

Comment: Shouldn't local.xml be in the layout folder, not the template folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will post down what it worked for me as a reference for others

adding this :

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav">  
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
</reference>
```

in the custom design tab of every categories does the trick.

Remember especially to add it in the parent category, thats what did it for me.

Comment: where to place this code?

Answer (score 14):

Based on stackexchange.com answer:
If you want to do it via XML you should edit catalog.xml

replace:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" 
    after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" />
```

with this:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">  
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
</block>
```

Comment: yes a classic clean method,+1 for that

Comment: I tried, but it simply doesn't work.
I belive that this is related to my custom template.
In my template "catalog.xml" there isn't these lines.
Anyway, I've read in stackexchange that the correct method is to work with the "local.xml" file.
Other than the -.xml- method, can you suggest me other way to achieve the desidered result?

Comment: What's the difference between <alias> and <child>? For me both works...

Comment: There is no difference in this particular case. You can use even <action method="unsetChild"><xyz>category_filter</xyz></action>

Comment: If like me you tried adding this into your local.xml you may then get this kind of error.... 
**"You cannot define a correlation name 'mycustomattribute' more than once"**
 because catalog/layer_view module is called twice-Explained here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524017/magento-layered-navigation-you-cannot-define-a-correlation-name-mycustomattrib

Use the  code posted by giancarlo below 
`<reference name="catalog.leftnav">  
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
</reference>`
but add into local.xml. this worked for me on 1.8

Answer (score 5):

Try this code first. Here we are trying to remove this via layout xml update

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
            <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

This will solve your problem.

If it didn't worked, then you need to do a block rewrite. For this you need to create a module. The block that you need to rewrite is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View`.

Module's activation file looks like this

File : `app/etc/modules/Avoid_CategoryFromLN.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
         <Avoid_CategoryFromLN>
             <active>true</active>
             <codePool>local</codePool>
         </Avoid_CategoryFromLN>
     </modules>
</config>
```

This is how rewrite configuration looks like

File : `app\code\local\Avoid/CategoryFromLN/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Avoid_CategoryFromLN>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Avoid_CategoryFromLN>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer_view>Avoid_CategoryFromLN_Block_Layer_View</layer_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now your rewrite block should posses this content

File : `app\code\local\Avoid/CategoryFromLN/Block/Layer/View.php`

```
<?php
class Avoid_CategoryFromLN_Block_Layer_View exteds Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View
{
    public function getFilters()
    {

        $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
        foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
            $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter');
        }

        return $filters;
    }
}
```

Here `getFilters()` is the method that actually includes category filters inside layered navigation filter. We just remove that code by rewriting the core class. That's it.

**Big Note:** : You should keep capital letters as it is. Dont make them small letters. If you do, it will not work. Magento is strict in these things :)
So revise all folder names, file names multiple times. Make sure you keep all names contents as it is

Now try again.

Comment: sorry, but editing the local.xml file does not gives any results.
regarding the creation of a module I have some doubts about it. I'm a magento "newbie" so please bear with me. This is what I've done to create a new module as suggested:
Create this new folder: "app\code\local\my_module_name\etc"
Create the config.xml file
Add the content you told me in the "config.xml" file
Create a new folder: "app\code\local\my_module_name\block\layer"
Create a new file called "view.php" 
Copy the content you suggested in the "view.php" file.
After this I try again, but nothing changes. Do I miss something?

Comment: Also, I've discovered this answer in stackexchange that offer another solution :
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31631/magento-1-9-remove-category-filter-in-layered-nav
But I belive that this should be modified to fit my template settings.

Comment: nope your condfigurations are wrong. I will update my answer for you

Comment: edited answer. Now it is a complete module. Feel free to use it. Please note you need to keep capital letters as it is

Comment: regarding the link that you pointed out, it is not ideal in your case. If you put `isAnchor` to `no`, then the entire layered navigation get disappeared.

Comment: Ok, I've followed your precious suggestions but now ,after the creation of the custom module (I really appreciate that, thanks) the entire layered navigation bar is gone. I would like to remove only the "Category" under the "browse by" , and mantain all other attributes for a quick navigation help.
I checked my configuration under the "manage category" and I saw that almost all my categories are checked with "is anchor: NO", can your solution be affected of the issue you warned me in you previous post?

Comment: yes. If you need layered navigation available in a category, then you need to set `isAnchor` to `yes`. Now you set them to `no`. That is why it is gone

Answer (score 1):

The unset-child solution in `local.xml` works well. Please note, that if you are working with enterprise edition the reference is called "`enterprisecatalog`":

```
<reference name="enterprisecatalog.leftnav">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>category_filter</alias>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Side-note: You may not find any corresponding child-block definitions in any of the core XML. This is due to the fact, that children like "`category_filter`" are created (hard-coded) in `_prepareLayout` function of the corresponding catalog layer view. By using `unsetChild` you can, however, remove the hard-coded added child.

Answer (score 0):

This is works
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/45249/9951

BUT

Also need add changes to
**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml**

like this

```
if($_filter != '' && $_filter->getItemsCount())
```

and also need changes to 
**/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php**

copy **/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php**

to **/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php**

and change method **canShowOptions()**

need change

```
if (&& $filter->getItemsCount())
```

to

```
if ($filter != '' && $filter->getItemsCount())
```

and try

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (on Magento 1.9).

Add these lines on your `local.xml` file:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

  <default>

    <reference name="left">

      <!-- Remove layered navigation block form catalog page -->
      <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>

      <!-- ... -->

    </reference>

    <!-- ... -->

  </default>

  <!-- ... -->

  <catalogsearch_result_index>

    <!-- Remove layered navigation from search result page -->
    <reference name="left">
      <action method="unsetChild">
        <child>catalogsearch.leftnav</child>
      </action>
    </reference>

  </catalogsearch_result_index>

  <!-- ... -->
```