# Hide categories in left navigation only for selected categories

Tags: layout, magento-1, layered-navigation

I want the left navigation menu to display the categories and subcategories only for selected categories. I still want to display the layered navigation. I added the following to the "Custom Layout Update" but it hides the whole content of the columns

```
<remove name="left"/>
```

How do I hide just the category block? I also tried the following but no luck:

```
<reference name="left">
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav"></remove>
</reference>
```

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/how-can-i-disable-filter-category-from-sidebar

Comment: Can you please add a screen shot ? I'm not sure what you want to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to create a custom design fallback because for my theme and brutally remove the div showing the categories in the left bar because none of the above solutions worked. The block name was correct though :( –

Comment: Could you explain briefly?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done through the admin.

Navigate to the category and under the `custom design` tab you should see `Custom Layout Update`. If you paste the XML in there it will also remove the block only for that category.

You may need to clear cache.

[image]

Comment: How can i Hide selected attributes for selected categories of products